# Is there a way i could implement a nested for loop in an anonymous function in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, for-loop, nested-loops, anonymous-function

I have to implement an anonymous function in MATLAB to take the Discrete Fourier Transform (DFT) of an N point matrix. It would be very simple to implement in a nested for loop:

```
function A=dftmat(N)
for k=0:1:N
for n=0:1:N
A(k+1,n+1)=exp(-2*pi*1i*k*n/N);
end
end
end;
```

but alas it must be in the form of dftmat = @(N) ...

Comment: You don't need an anonymous function, you simply need a function handle. See the [documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/creating-a-function-handle.html) to learn how to create a function handle to an existing function.

Comment: An anonymous function can only contain a single statement. If you really need to implement the DFT in an anonymous function you can build the DFT matrix and matrix-multiply by the input. But that has O(N^3) complexity or slightly less, whereas the `fft` function has roughly O(N log(N)) complexity. Also, your question says "take the DFT", whereas your code computes the DFT matrix, which is a different thing

Comment: This anonymous function will do it: `@(x)fft(x)`. Why do you need it to be an anonymous function though? That is a weird requirement.

Comment: Instead of loop you can use vectorization: `dftmat = @(N)exp(-2*pi*1i*(0:1:N).'.*(0:1:N)/N);`.

Comment: Tysm Rahnema1 that's what i was looking for